# Showing the limit of the discrete category defines the usual product.

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation, limits-colimits

How can we see that the categorical limit of the diagram $F$ from the discrete 2 object category to sets is isomorphic to the usual product $\{(x,y)\mid x\in X, y\in Y\}$ defined elementwise on sets. Certainly if im$(F)=\{X,Y\}$ then $X\times Y$ is the apex of a cone over $F$ using the projection map.

I think the correct approach should be to consider sets strictly larger, smaller or equal in size to $X\times Y$ because that would allow us to construct (or perhaps fail to construct) maps through $X\times Y$ but I'm not sure how to formalise this.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking for. If you define a product of sets via its universal property (what we usually do in naive set theory or structural set theory) then there isn’t really anything to show (besides noting that the universal property on elements implies the universal property for arbitrary functions). If you have some other construction of a product in mind (I don’t know how they are defined in material set theories like ZFC) please specify it :)

Comment: @PrudiiArca I've edited to describe the definition I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Fix a set $\{*\}$ with precisely one element and recall that elements of a set $X$ are precisely the functions $\{*\}\rightarrow X$.

By definition the product set $X\times Y=\{(x,y)\mid x\in X, y\in Y\}$ satisfies that for any pair of functions $x:\{*\}\rightarrow X$, $y:\{*\}\rightarrow Y$ there exists a unique function $(x,y):\{*\}\rightarrow X\times Y$ satisfying $pr_X \circ (x,y) = x$ and $pr_Y \circ (x,y) = y$. This is to say: the set theoretic product satisfies the universal property of a categorical products for cones with apex $\{*\}$.

What about general cones with an arbitrary set $T$ as apex? Consider two functions $f:T\rightarrow X$ and $g:T\rightarrow Y$. We need to show that there exists a unique function $(f,g): T \rightarrow X\times Y$ with $pr_X\circ (f,g) = f$ and $pr_Y\circ (f,g)= g$. Now note that a function may be defined by specifying what it does on the elements of its domain. So if we know what we have to do for each element $t\in T$, we are done. Recall again that an element $t\in T$ is nothing but a function $t:\{*\}\rightarrow T$. Postcomposing with the functions $f,g$ we thus get two functions $f\circ t: \{*\}\rightarrow X$ and $g\circ t: \{*\} \rightarrow Y$, which amount by definition to the elements $f(t)\in X$ and $g(t)\in Y$. By the discussion in the first paragraph they induce a unique element $(f(t),g(t))\in X\times Y$. But this means that if we want to have a function $(f,g):T \rightarrow X\times Y$ (with given constraints) it *must* send $t$ to $(f(t),g(t))$. This already shows uniqueness, it is left to show that the assignment $t\mapsto (f(t),g(t))$ is indeed a welldefined function.

To recap: The set theoretic product satisfies the universal property of a categorical product, since it does for cones with apex $\{*\}$ and for general cones with apex $T$ the functions are completely determined on what the do for elements of $T$, which are functions $\{*\}\rightarrow T$.